# What is the significance of the title "Agora"?

Tags: title, agora

One thing that's haunting me after watching the movie "Agora" is the title, What was the significance of this title?

Comment: agora - phobia?

Comment: @Richard  : This title relevance with the movie

Comment: Greek word: αγορα, transscription: agora, translates as: market.

Answer (score 11):

It's from the Greek word "[Agora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agora)", the meaning of which was

> "gathering place" or "assembly".

Many sources discuss and confirm this, but I like Roger Ebert's [description](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/agora-2010) the best:

> [Hypatia's] father Theon (Michael Lonsdale) was the curator of the Library of
>   Alexandria, which had as its mission "collecting all the world's
>   knowledge." Scholars traveled there from across the ancient world,
>   doing research and donating manuscripts. It was destroyed by
>   Christians in 391 A.D., and "Agora" takes place in the years
>   surrounding that incalculable loss.
>
> The film's title refers to a name for the public assembly places in
>   ancient Greek city-states. The library was such an agora, and we see
>   Hypatia teaching a class of young men who listen to her with open
>   admiration.

Answer (score 11):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agora_(film))

> The title of the film takes its name from the [agora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agora), a gathering place
>   in ancient Greece, similar to the Roman forum.

This was explicitly confirmed in a [huffpo interview](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/melissa-silverstein/interview-with-rachel-wei_b_593335.html) with the film's lead actress; Rachel Weisz

> **W&H:** *The film was huge in Spain. A blockbuster. Can you explain the word Agora?*
>
> **RW:** *It’s an ancient Greek word that means market place. It’s a place where people met. And I guess the premise of the film, or the
>   conceit of the title is, the earth is an Agora. It’s a meeting place
>   for humans who don’t get along.*

Comment: As an aside, "agoraphobia" comes from "agora", and reveals it's true meaning as a "fear of crowds, or social situations", rather than a fear of being outdoors, which many people seem to think is the meaning.